# I need to split a string based on some character array of separators and not lose these separators in string

Tags: c#, string, split

for example:

```
string input = "+hello-ali!56*89";
```

and I want the output like below:

```
+ 
hello
-
ali
!
56
*
89
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: you can check whether character is a-z or 0-9, if not then you can split it.

Comment: If you know all separator characters, just replace them by itself and a character that is not expected in your data (blank, €, etc.) and then split by this character.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex,

```
string input = "+hello-ali!56*89";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+|.+?")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "+hello-ali!56*89";

var a = Regex.Split(input, @"(\W)");  // { "","+","hello","-","ali","!","56","*","89" }

var b = Regex.Split(input, @"(\w+)"); // { "+","hello","-","ali","!","56","*","89","" }
```

`\W` matches any "non-word character":
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z#NonWordCharacter

Answer (score 0):

```
var param = new [] {',', '!'}
```

you can use `.Split(param)` and get an array of strings separated by your characters, then you can mix them together in the order you want

Comment: This will not include the signs of the splitting in the result

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option for you.

```
var values = new List<string>();

string input = "+hello-ali!56*89";
var delimiters = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '!' };
//split the strings using the delimiters, eliminate empty strings
var tempValues = input.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var curChar = 0;
// iterate through the input string finding your original strings
// include the delimiter
foreach (var val in tempValues)
{
    var matchCharStart = input.IndexOf(val, curChar,   StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (matchCharStart <= 0) continue;
        values.Add(input.Substring(matchCharStart - 1, val.Length + 1));
        if (matchCharStart > 0) curChar = matchCharStart + val.Length;
    }
}
```